# want to get the file pointer after finding the string in a one single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need current pointer just after my string is found. Below code not printing anything.

```
import requests
pname = input("Enter your product name:")

u = 'https://www.ebay.in/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR10.TRC0.A0.H0.Xhello.TRS0&_nkw='
url = u + pname + '&_sacat=0'
temp = []
r = requests.get(url)
with open("qwe.txt", "r+") as file:
    file.write(str(r.content))
    print(file.tell())
    file.close()
with open("qwe.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'lvpicinner full-width picW' in line:
            break
            print(file.tell())
            file.seek(0)
```

Comment: you may want to take a look at beautifulsoup or another scraping mod. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32667/ebay-scraper-with-beautifulsoup&_sacat=0

Comment: `file.close()` is not needed since it's performed automatically when exiting `with` scope. Also `file.seek(0)` doesn't seem to have any meaning. Actually I'm not sure if it modifying file pointer while iterating over it isn't dangerous .

Answer (score 0):

Put `break` clause after `print(file.tell())` and `file.seek(0)` like so:

```
for line in file:
    if 'lvpicinner full-width picW' in line:
        print(file.tell())
        file.seek(0)
        break
```

And if then nothing would print, then there is no such occurrences.

Comment: yeah! I tried putting break  clause after asking for tell. It gives me an osError  about disabled tell() function because of next().